# Ruby read file that has placeholder and need to print the file contents with variables to be placed

Tags: ruby

I am reading an HTML file with 2  "%s" in the contents, and want to display the content and the "%s" with my customized variable. 
my code is like this:

```
header = File.read('header.html')
puts header %["test1", "test2"]
```

But when i tried to render the file, nothing is showing up. Wondering why

Comment: This works fine for me; what exactly prints to your console?

Comment: if i drop the %["test1", "test2"], then everything prints, it prints
"%s"
"%s". but for code above, it doesn't print anything